# Makefile: No rule to make target

Tags: makefile

I've got two very similar makefiles but they behave differently.
I don't understand why ...

option 1:

```
all: aa
    @echo made
a% : b%
    @echo ba
ba : c
```

fails with

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'c', needed by 'ba'.  Stop.
```

I expect this since c doesn't exist.

option 2 is identical but without the echo:

```
all: aa
    @echo made
a% : b%
ba : c
```

This one fails with

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'aa', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```

which is weird, since there is a rule for 'aa'.

Why are these two makefiles behaving differently?

Thanks

Comment: First of all make sure you leave one line between rules and that the recipe has only one tab from the left margin. I run the test myself and found that if you remove the `ba : c ` rule and the `ba` file already exists, it works. If you put the rule back with any recipe, make tries to check if ba is up to date so it tries the `ba : c ` rule, and fails because there is no rule for `c`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule for `aa`.  Your rule:

```
a% : b%
```

with no recipe is not doing what you think it's doing.  A [pattern rule with no recipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html) *deletes* the pattern rule.  So basically this line is a no-op (since you didn't have a pattern rule like that before).  You could remove this line and get identical behavior.

Comment: I don't think the lack of recipe in `ba : c` in option1 is the problem. I have used rules without recipe once just to declare prerequisites while another more general role do the work.

Comment: ???  I didn't say that the lack of recipe in `ba : c` in option 1 is the problem.  According to the question, the results of option 1 are understood and correct.  The question is why option 2 behaves differently.  I said that the _pattern rule_ `a% : b%` in option 2, without any recipe, does NOT declare a prerequisite.  It has no effect (see the link to the GNU make manual in my answer).  The behavior of pattern rules with no recipe is totally different than the behavior of explicit rules like `ba : c` with no prerequisite.  That's why option 2 doesn't behave as the OP expects.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario-1, I run the test myself and found that if you remove the `ba : c` rule and the `ba` file already exists, it works. If you put the rule back with any recipe, make tries to check if ba is up to date so it tries the `ba : c` rule, and fails because there is no rule for `c`.

If you don't want a rule to try to "recreate" a file (meaning go to apply other rules), but only to check if it exists to apply the current rule then use  double colons for the rule `::`.